# Flutter - 'initialValue == null || controller == null': is not true. error

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to set an initial value for the text field. But I Can't set the initial value in text form field. I'm getting this error `'initialValue  == null || controller == null': is not true` .

code:

```
Widget buildFirstName(BuildContext context) {
 valueBuilder = valueBuild();

return TextFormField(
  controller: firstNameController,
  initialValue: valueBuilder,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: "Enter Name",
    fillColor: Colors.white,
    hintStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1.0),
        fontFamily: "SFProText-Regular"),
  ),
  validator: validatingName,
);
}
```

Comment: You can't have both an initialValue and a controller

Comment: Then how to set initial value and how can I track the value entered by the user in the field

Comment: just using a TextEditingController :), but you can't use both (initialValue + controller)

Comment: you can set an initial value in your TextEditingController when its constructor is created

Answer (score 240, accepted):

You can't use both `initialValue` and `controller` at the same time. So, it's better to use `controller` as you can set default text in its constructor.

Here is an example.

```
// Create the controller. 
final controller = TextEditingController(text: "Your initial value");

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return TextFormField(
    controller: controller, // Assign it here. 
    // ...
  );
}
```

To get the value entered by the user, use:

```
controller.text
```

Comment: i am creating a form so that when user filling the form for the first time the text field's initial value  has to be empty but once he  completed creating the form  and submitted it and when he tries to edit the details of him for eg. name then field should have initial value which the user entered previously

Comment: You have to Use OnSaved Method to save the value of the Form & then use it in edit mode.In the Init Method - firstNameController.text = ''; give it an Empty Value for the First Run & in Edit Mode give it firstNameController.text = 'Value';
You have to use two variables 1 Bool ( for Edit) 2 value (OnSaved Method).

Comment: You can use SharedPreferences for this case. Initially the default value is going to be `null` and when user saves something, you can save that data too and retrieve it later on and simply put that data with if else condition to work with `controller`.

Comment: Why is a controller required to update a control? It seems complex

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have controller and initialValue for TextFormField at the same time which we know from @CopsOnRoad thread.

Besides of passing default text to the constructor of controller, you can modify the value of the TextFormField by assigning value to the controller text

```
firstNameController.text = valueBuilder;
```

Answer (score 0):

`controller..setText("Your initial value text")`

Comment: Regardless that your answer is correct or not, you are encouraged to edit it to explain why this is the best answer to the question.